# Matlab exits without error upon clear mex with openMP

Tags: c++, matlab, openmp, mex

I ran into a weird case where Matlab closes without an error.

I have the following mex file that uses OpenMP

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "mex.h"
#include "omp.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int num_threads;
    int kx;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (kx = 0; kx < 100; kx++)
    {
        if (kx == 0) num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
        float tmp = (float)kx;
    }
    mexPrintf("Num threads: %i\n", num_threads);
}
```

When I compile this with `mex COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /openmp" main.cpp -output test_openmp` and run it, it works as expected

```
>> test_openmp()
Num threads: 8
```

However, if I immediately add a `clear mex` after the call, Matlab crashes and immediately closes without error report.

```
>> test_openmp(); clear mex
```

If I add a `pause(1)`, there is no crash

```
>> test_openmp(); pause(1); clear mex
```

This is a problem in another program where call a mex program can case an error and I need to do:

```
try
    mexprogram()
catch ME
    clear mexprogram
end
```

Does anybody know what is going on? When I run Matlab from the command line, I see the following return code: -1073741819. Attaching the debugger does not give any info.

I am using MSVC 2022 and Matlab R2021b.

---

**Update**

Linking against the intel openMP implementation `libiomp5md.lib` fixes the issue!
Compiling from MATLAB with

```
mex -v -g COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /openmp" LINKFLAGS="$LINKFLAGS /nodefaultlib:vcomp" '-LC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2021b\bin\win64\' -llibiomp5md.lib main.cpp -output test_openmp_intel
```

Comment: It looks like perhaps the openMP context is not properly cleared when you call `clear mex`. Not entirely sure how to make OpenMP wait until all its created contexts are dead, but I think it may be something along those lines

Comment: You don’t ever need to clear a mex-file from memory, unless you’re developing it and you want to rebuild a dependent library without exiting MATLAB. The mex file itself will be cleared automatically when you rebuild it. Why are you clearing the mex file? What is your use case?

Comment: @CrisLuengo My normal build system is cmake, which I run externally. So If the program err'd, I have to manually type clear mex. Therefore I add it to test files, to be able to rebuild from my ide without going to matlab.

Comment: Another use case is that I have cleanup routines to e.g. free memory on the GPU in MexAtExit. Or I call clear <mexfile> to delete static variables, and initialize the program with new data.

Comment: Adding a delay like this works for developing and testing, and in the real use case there probably would be more time between a potential reset and new call to the mexfile. It just feels unsatisfactory to have this potential issue, but I can work around it.

Comment: The last use cases I usually solve by adding a call syntax `mexprogram('clear')`. In part because I don't like using the `clear` command, but mostly because I tend to lock the mex files with static variables, and you can't clear a locked mex file.

Comment: But yes, I do understand why you'd want to fix this. I wouldn't know where to start though. It might be related to mixing different OpenMP implementations within the same process. MATLAB uses OpenMP internally. See here for some details on mixing OpenMP implementations: https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl/blob/master/multiple_openmp.md

Comment: What happens if you add code for the mex routine to lock itself, then at the calling level unlock it first before clearing it? Will that result in enough pause to avoid the crash?

Comment: @JamesTursa Locking and unlocking still resulted in crashing

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! This was indeed the issue, linking against the intel openmp implementation that comes with matlab fixes it!

Comment: @CrisLuengo sorry going slightly offtopic. By default, the intel openmp implementation returns the number of cores for `omp_get_max_threads` (4), whereas the msvc openmp returns the number of logical processors (8). Do you know why is this different? My code runs twice as slow now. Is there any downside in manually setting `omp_set_num_threads` to the number of logical cores?

Comment: No, there is none. If you know how many threads you need, then you specify that number. You can even choose more than the number of logical processors, if that were somehow advantageous to your program. Some modern software create tens or hundreds of threads, where most threads sit idle most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from mixing different openmp implementations. Linking with the intel openmp lib that comes with Matlab solves the issue.

Compile with

```
mex -v -g COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /openmp" LINKFLAGS="$LINKFLAGS /nodefaultlib:vcomp" '-LC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2021b\bin\win64\' -llibiomp5md.lib main.cpp -output test_openmp_intel
```